# Striping symbols from a binary (windows)

Tags: windows, security, binaryfiles, strip

Our company creates an application that runs both on Mac and Windows.
In Mac, we're using the 'strip' command to remove the symbols from the binary
for security reasons and also for lightening the file size.

Is there a parallel command that we can use in Windows / MSVC ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Compile in release mode and don't distribute the symbol (pdb) files